# Is Azure's User.Read permission required for OAuth consent forms?

Tags: azure, oauth

My multi-tenant Azure application requires only the app-level EWS legacy permission `full_access_as_app` to run. This app-level permission can only be consented to by an administrator---it's extremely powerful because it gives the app read and write permissions over every EWS mailbox in a tenancy.

If I, as an admin for my Azure tenancy, grant my application only this single permission behind the scenes in AAD configuration, everything works fine when I run the application for my tenancy.

However when you create a new app in Azure, Azure always assumes you will want the user-level Graph API `User.Read` permission automatically. When you try to remove the permission you get this ominous warning:
[image: This scope is required for proper application functionality]

And in the case when I leave it out, interactive OAuth consent forms don't work. The error message looks like this.

> The client has not listed any permissions for 'AAD Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Or, The admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, Check the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the configured client application identifier. Please contact your admin to fix the configuration or consent on behalf of the tenant.

In other words, it appears that the application won't be able to run for anyone else's tenancy because their admins can't consent to it.

My hypothesis is that this is because Azure is using the `User.Read` permission to check whether the person signing in through the OAuth form is an administrator. In other words this permission is needed just this one time, before the application is ever run for the admin's tenancy.

Looking at the actual OAuth consent form, this does appear to be the case.The app wants to sign in and read my profile, to check if I am admin... or so it seems to me.
[image: The app would like to: Use Exchange Web Services with full access to all mailboxes. Sign in and read user profile.]

**Am I right about this**? Documentation I have been able to find is rather scanty.